# Pattern to find specific object in PHP in given text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have trouble to find specific object with `preg_match_all` pattern. I have a text. But I would like to find just one specific

Like I have a string of text

```
sadasdasd:{"website":["https://bitcoin.org/"]tatic/cloud/img/coinmarketcap_grey_1.svg?_=60ffd80');display:inline-block;background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:contain;width:239px;height:41px;} .cqVqre.cmc-logo--size-large{width:263px;height:45px;}
/* sc-component-id: sc-2wt0ni-0 */
```

However I just need to find `"website":["https://bitcoin.org/"]`. Where website is dynamic data. Such as website can be a google `"website":["https://google.com/"]`

Right now I have something like this. That's just return a bulk of urls. I need just specific

```
$pattern = '#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $parsePage, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

I am really bad in patterns and stuck on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the data that follows the website prefix until the next `"` comes `[^"]+`:

```
$parsePage = <<<PAGE
sadasdasd:{"website":["https://bitcoin.org/"]tatic/cloud/img/coinmarketcap_grey_1.svg?_=60ffd80');display:inline-block;background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:contain;width:239px;height:41px;} .cqVqre.cmc-logo--size-large{width:263px;height:45px;}
/* sc-component-id: sc-2wt0ni-0 */';
PAGE;

$pattern = '#"website":\["(https?://[^"]+)#';
preg_match($pattern, $parsePage, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

The `matches[1]` is to get the first match (what matches the content inside the parentheses).

This prints:

```
https://bitcoin.org/
```

as you can check [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1f69edf241bbf141d18846148f144f563978589)

Comment: However there are can be a bulk of urls. I just need url from the "website":[""]

Comment: Ok, check the updated code then

Comment: Thank you. Love you